# Java Spring Boot not logging exceptions

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I have a spring boot rest service. When I send a request to the service, I would like to log whether or not it was a successful request or not. If the rest service is successfully, logger.info (any logger will be logged even logger.error) will be logged to the console. However, when an SQL exception is thrown, it does not log the logger.error portion to console. How do I get it so if an exception is thrown, it would also log that portion to the console?

Here is the test method:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory   

public String testMethod(){
    try{

        LOGGER.info("running test method");

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        Connection test = DriverManager.getConnection(
                datasourceUrl,datasourceUsername,datasourcePassword);
        //Select data
        Statement stmt = test.createStatement();

        InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testMethodSQL.sql");
        String insertTableSQL = IOUtils.toString(input);

         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = prod.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        }

        test.close();

        LOGGER.info("test Method successfully ran");

        return "Done";
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("Error found: {}", e);
        return "An error occured: " +  e;
    }

}
```

Here is my logback.xml file:

```
<configuration>
<appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</root>

</configuration>
```

For example, when an exception is thrown the results would print out:

```
{"@timestamp":"2019-02-12T10:07:05.989-05:00","@version":1,"message":"running test method","logger_name":"com.test","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-2","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"RequestId":"6D71709D5A1A4C83876B68A661D696E3"}

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST_TABLE.SYS_C0013283) violated
```

However, it does not log the Logger.error portion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable logging, create a `application.properties` file in the root of the resources folder, And you need add logging level in your `application.properties`

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.com.mkyong=DEBUG
```

Or just add those in your logback.xml

```
    <logger name="com.mkyong" level="debug"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </root>
```

Comment: I have tried adding the debug level on my logback.xml and it doesn't log the "logger.error" portion when an exception is thrown still

Comment: you use  `LOGGER.error("Error found: {}", e);` in your code, for me `root level` should be `"error"` not `"info"`

Comment: ERROR level could not be enough if , like me, you have a bug in your @ExceptionHandler, to debug it : `logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc=DEBUG`

Answer (score 6):

It could be your IDE suppressing the log entry. I encountered this recently with IntelliJ. Check if there is an option to expand your log entries

[image: IDE example]

I ended up with two minimal example projects before spotting the option to expand the logs. One project used spring + logback and the other just used logback. Weirdly for the example with logback only IntelliJ didn't perform any supression.